# Python multiprocessing execute a function before Pool closes

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pool

I'm using python's `multiprocessing` module for parallelising and processing my data. Before I close this process pool, I want to execute a function for each of the sub-processes that are spawned. How can I achieve this?

eg, below is a sample code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def publish_metadata():
    print(str(metadata))

metadata = []

def process_row(row={}):
    global metadata
    metadata.append("something")
    # process the data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pl = [////] # list to process data, each row is a dict
    pool = Pool(processes=10)
    pool.map(process_row, pl)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I want to run this function `publish_metadata` which will contain sub-process specific metadata, before I merge and close process pool (`pool.close`). How can I achieve that?

Comment: I guess the *"normal"* way would be to submit 10 tasks to the pool with `None` as parameter before closing the pool. Then change `process_row` to check whether its parameter is `None` and if so do the exit processing, otherwise proceed with regular processing. Maybe Google *"poison pill"*.